# Two properties views

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to have two properties views in Eclipse RCP application? 
I have two separate plugins, each is responsible for it's own properties view. 
How can I show them both at once?

Comment: Do you really want to display two property views (and the other two editors/views the properties are for) at the same time? Your UI may be very cluttered.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you need but in the top right of the properties view is a small view menu. After clicking on this menu a can choose 'new Properties view'.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how can I define that my properties plugin uses exactly this second view?

Answer (score 0):

Each property view that your plug-ins contribute will add to the existing properties view already provided.

I don't think there is any restriction on the number of property contributions any one plug-in can contribute.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easiest, you could always create your own secondary 'Properties View' to display the properties of your second window.  This would just be your own view that happens to look and behave like a properties view, but is not the included one.

Using two instances of the included properties view will cause you headaches when trying to distinguish them programmatically, or when managing workbench/window selection.

Comment: But how can I do it, if I have only one org.eclipse.ui.views.PropertySheet and this PropertySheet is already associated view some view?

Comment: That's what I was trying to get at - make it your own view, and **not** an `org.eclipse.ui.views.PropertySheet`, but looks and feels similar to one from the user's perspective.  It'll be a bit of effort up front to create the view, but will pay off by making it trivial to display them both at once and easier to distinguish between them and manage selection.